# DRF response list field

Tags: django-rest-framework, response, listfield

How can I get response in an array format in Django drf? 
I am new in python-drf programming. kindly help with solutions.

I just want the team_users in an array format, but now it is returning in an array with each letter seperated by quotes.

> ```
> {
>     "id": 3,
>     "team_name": "team 3",
>     "team_icon": "/media/icon/underground_3Dz5sfD.png",
>     "team_users": [
>         "[",
>         "'",
>         "s",
>         "k",
>         "a",
>         "r",
>         "a",
>         "n",
>         "7",
>         "1",
>         "4",
>         "@",
>         "g",
>         "m",
>         "a",
>         "i",
>         "l",
>         ".",
>         "c",
>         "o",
>         "m",
>         "'",
>         ",",
>         " ",
>         "'",
>         "s",
>         "a",
>         "m",
>         "p",
>         "l",
>         "e",
>         "1",
>         "2",
>         "3",
>         "@",
>         "g",
>         "m",
>         "a",
>         "i",
>         "l",
>         ".",
>         "c",
>         "o",
>         "m",
>         "'",
>         "]"
>     ]
> },
> ```

required format is :

> ```
>     "id": 3,
>     "team_name": "team 3",
>     "team_icon": "/media/icon/underground_3Dz5sfD.png",
>     "team_users": ["first_email", "second_email"]
> ```

This is the code in serializers.py

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        team_users = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.EmailField(min_length=0, max_length=100))


        class Meta():
            model=Team
            fields = ('id','team_name', 'team_icon', 'team_users')
```

models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team_icon = models.ImageField()
    team_users = models.EmailField()
```

In views.py

```
class GetTeam(APIView):


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data_list = []
        teams = models.Team.objects.all()
        for team in teams:
            data_list.append(serializers.TeamSerializer(team).data)
        return Response(data_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solution is to use 'SerializerMethodField'

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    team_users = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_team_users(self, obj):
        return [x.email for x in obj.team_users]
```

Also depends on your team user model, but you can tailor this to your needs.

Comment: Got this as error AttributeError 
'str' object has no attribute 'email'

Comment: That's what I meant, you need to add your models to your question. Without that I only assumed that team user is a model with email attribute.

Comment: can you please help me with the problem, added the models and views

Comment: you model design is not probably what you want, and it is out of scope to do here on SO. You probably want a teamuser to be a model and add relation to the team model so you can multiple users in a team.

Answer (score 1):

```
class GetTeam(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        teams = models.Team.objects.all()
        return Response(serializers.TeamSerializer(team, many=True).data)
```

[If the field is used to represent a to-many relationship, you should add the many=True flag to the serializer field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).